# Ping IPs — One time or multiple times?

Tags: c#, ping

I'm using the below code to ping the IP Address and check if it is online. 
Now just want to know, this C#'s `ping.Send(ipAddress)` will do just one ping or three times?

```
Ping ping = new Ping();
PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(ipAddress);

if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
    // Proceed as normal.
}
else
{
    // Send email to Admin.
}
```

Comment: I'm worried about what assumptions `// Proceed as normal` is making. All that `pingReply` tells you is that, at some point in the recent past, `ipAddress` was responding to ping requests. It *does not* tell you that some other service running on `ipAddress` is available and will be able to perform any particular piece of processing work successfully (nor even that future pings will succeed). *No* amount of pre-checking can protect you from the fact that the network and remote machines aren't under your code's control and so you need to write that code defensively *anyway*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree. But this is just to send some information as email alert. For example, I will check each one hour if the IP is working, and it fails all the time, we have to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One call to `ping.Send` will send one ICMP package. Nothing in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcc2xffs.aspx) indicates there are multiple attempts made:

> Attempts to send an Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) echo message to the specified computer, and receive a corresponding ICMP echo reply message from that computer.

Comment: [Here is the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/NetworkInformation/ping.cs,eb2dfd41e9774d4a) which seconds your answer.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman So if I want to do multiple pings, should I use while loop or use ping.Send(IP,timeOut) ?

Comment: Timeout is useful when you want to wait longer until a single package fails. If you want to make three attempts, you have to make a `for` or `while` loop indeed.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I think, I need the time out. For example, I want to try the IP for ( say) 20 seconds. For all the seconds, if it is not available, it means it is offline.

Comment: I guess you mean you want to send 20 packages (for example) with a timeout of 1 second. Or one single package and wait 20 seconds for it.

Comment: I think one single package and wait 20 seconds. But I don't have much experience in Networking, which one will be good ?

Comment: If that single package gets lost for some reason, you are waiting for 20 seconds for nothing. If you send 20 packages, and you get back 1, 5 or 20, it says something about the reliability of the connection or service.

Answer (score 0):

It will do one ping like the description of the method says.

> Attempts to send an Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) echo message with the specified data buffer to the computer that has the specified IPAddress, and receive a corresponding ICMP echo reply message from that computer. This method allows you to specify a time-out value for the operation.

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf697k33(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Uhm, that is the same answer already given 5 minutes ago. No need to repeat that.

Comment: @lucccas Appreciated your post. But please read 'How to answer' section in stack.

Comment: Tried to answer befor the first post was online.